# I'm looking for a proof of Polya-Bertrandias Theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-analysis

I'm looking for a proof of Polya-Bertrandias rationality criterion in english (not the one from Amice).

Comment: for reference, the proof in French is on page 175 and following of [this book](https://mattbakerblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/amice_les-nombres-p-adiques.pdf) --- I would just pass the text through Google translate, it's mostly formulas and little text.